# Scope of length of a given list

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, local, python-nonlocal

I'm learning about scopes of python variables: global, local, nonlocal, and built-in. And I'm having trouble with identifying the scope of following variable(var_5) in each line (1,2,3 7 4).

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
var_5 = len(list) - - - - - -(1)
print("var_1: ", val_5) - - -(2)

def len(list_a):
   return list_a
var_5= len(list)  - - - - - - (3)
print("var_1: ", val_5) - - - (4)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no list_a, val_5 defined in the code given here.

Comment: `list` is a keyword in Python, you should avoid using it as a variable.